# How to change <ion-item> into <ion-input> by clicking on the <ion-item>?

Tags: ionic4

HTML code:

```
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item  *ngFor = "let item of items;let i=index" >{{item.itemName}}</ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

I wish to convert any particular ion-item into an input field when a user clicks on the item field. Is there a way to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

With angular you can do a combination of template checks and listening for user click on `<ion-item>`.

```
    // you must map itemVisible to true for each item you have.
    // I don't know what kind of values you're dealing with
    items = [
        {
          itemName: 'item1',
          itemVisible: true
        },
        {
          itemName: 'item2',
          itemVisible: true
        },
        {
          itemName: 'item3',
          itemVisible: true
        }
      ];

    constructor() {}
```

```
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" 
              (click)="item.itemVisible = !item.itemVisible">
      <div *ngIf="item.itemVisible; else ionInput">
        {{item.itemName}}
      </div> 
      <ng-template #ionInput>
        <ion-input placeholder="{{item.itemName}}"></ion-input>
      </ng-template>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```